# Lenovo M900 won’t detect bootable ubuntu usb

Tags: boot, usb

Hi I am trying to install Ubuntu 21.10 or LTS on a Lenovo M900 10FL, but it just won’t detect the live usb (tried rpi imager and balena etcher). The desktop iso is always downloaded from official Ubuntu homepage.

I disabled secure boot in bios, moved all the usb lines to the top of the boot order, set boot mode to legacy and also tried to hit enter during boot then f12 so I get to the menu where I can select where I want to boot from. But whatever I try I never see the USB device in the list (its only the internal ssd or windows boot manager.

Please help I am very mich stuck here for the past hours.

Comment: Can you make a dvd disc with these Ubuntu image?

Comment: Are you sure that the installation media is valid? Did you [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) checksums before flashing?  Once you've determined that you have valid installation media, it's up to your motherboard's configuration to determine how to boot a bootable volume. You may want to review the documentation for the motherboard or contact the manufacturer for support.

Comment: A dvd wont help me as this PC only has usb ports no drives. 

I believe both the pi imager and balena etcher do a “verify” at the end, but then again, I just put the usb in an older chiligreen laptop and it is booting from it (although it takes ages and is still loading, but it definitely is booting of the usb).

Comment: The old laptop just fully booted so the usb is fine. I am not sure what you mean by reading the documentation of the motherboard.

Comment: When I go into the lenovo diagnostics, I can see the usb in the motherboard section 

Comment: Media creation tools only verify the *flash* not the *download*.  But if the USB is bootable on another device then unfortunately the barrier that you are facing is figuring out how to boot a USB from your particular motherboard. If you can't figure it out going thru the settings, read the manual.  Users manuals and documentation are often posted on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: All test in diagnostics passed. 

I tried the manual but unfortunately it is rather vague..

Comment: Could a bios update help? Its from 2016. Although the old laptop has like 2005 or something lol

Comment: Perhaps. Is there a new BIOS available? **Definitely** follow the documentation carefully if you flash a new BIOS. All motherboards are different and if you use the wrong file, take the wrong actions, or interrupt the flash, it can brick your board.

Comment: Yea i dont feel overly confident doing that :/ would it be possible to install ubuntu over lan?

Comment: Have you set the BOOT flag on the USB drive's bootable partition?

Comment: This is honestly the first time I hear about a boot flag. I only flashed the usb with balena etcher.  Not sure if this does it or I would need to do that manually. How would I do that? I have a working ubuntu desktop on the old laptop so i could use that to do it?

Comment: If you flashed a valid Ubuntu ISO using etcher, it will be bootable.

Comment: So I decided to give a bios update a go and downloaded the fwj9bcusa.iso from https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/hu/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre-m-series-desktops/thinkcentre-m900/10fl/10fls3ax00/s4x27926/downloads/ds105487-flash-bios-update-intel-b150-for-thinkcentre-m700-tiny-thinkcentre-m800-m900-m900x-tiny I flashed this with startup disk creator this time, but this usb is also not detected as a bootable device in my bios

Comment: I also stumbled across this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqJBniwj1Mg where the internal ssd is wiped and its mentioned, that the usb will then appear as a bootable device, but honestly this sounds a bit scary as I might end up without an os on the ssd and without the ability to boot from usb - I guess I could try to take this ssd out, but another hdd in wipe that and see how it goes? Do you guys see any reason, why this should make the difference?

Comment: I reset windows 10 Enterprise, so now I have an admin account and I guess that’s fine for me now, but I couldn’t solve the booting from usb. If I boot into windows and go into the boot menu, I have the option to select my usb to boot from, but if I select it, windows just reboots normally 